# Viewing a geojson as 3D in cesium

Tags: javascript, cesium, 3d-model

I have a geojson with height informations in it. I tried adding the geojson to the scene using

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
sceneMode : Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE3D,
timeline : false,
animation : false
});

var dataSource = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('../../SampleData/Buildings_3D_Elevation.geojson');
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
viewer.zoomTo(dataSource);
```

I can view the data as below. What should be done to use the height information and view as 3D?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to extrude polygons:

```
entity.polygon.extrudedHeight = entity.properties.your_height_field
```

You may need to loop over records, for example:

```
    var p = dataSource.entities.values;   
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
         p.polygon.extrudedHeight = entity.properties.your_height_field
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is wrong. Here is the correct example:

```
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
<script>
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
    var dataSource = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('buildings.geojson').then(
        function(dataSource) {
            var p = dataSource.entities.values;
            for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                p[i].polygon.extrudedHeight = 15; // or height property
            }
            viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
            viewer.zoomTo(dataSource);
        }
    );
</script>
```